# how to prove $\int_{0}^{l_1}f(x)\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{l_2}g(x)\,dx$?

Tags: calculus

if $$
\int_{0}^{l_1} f(x)x\,dx = \int_{0}^{l_2}g(x)x\,dx
$$
where $l_1>l_2, f(x) \ge0, g(x)\ge 0 ,f(l_1)=g(l_2)=0,f(0)=g(0) $

is $\int_{0}^{l_1}f(x)\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{l_2}g(x)\,dx$ true?

If it is ture, how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

As the value of the integral, doesn't depend on what happens at one point, we can neglect the conditions $f(0)=0,g(0)=0$,etc.
Now as $\int_0^{l_2}xf(x)dx=\int_0^{l_1}xf(x)\chi_{[0,l2]}(x)dx$, (where $\chi_E$ is the function that has value 1 in the set E and 0 outside it), the condition $l_1>l_2$ doesn't matter.
So, your question is reduced to, if $\int_0^lx(f(x)-g(x))dx=0$, is $\int_0^lf(x)-g(x)dx=0$. But this is clearly not true as $l=1,f(x)=1,g(x)=3x$ shows.